# Algorithmically finite-dimensional (noncommutative) algebras.

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

Can anyone help to find some information about these structures?

Comment: What is "algorithmically finite-dimensional algebra"?

Comment: A Google search for the term finds only this question. -- Maybe you could clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Possibly the term resulted from a translation from Russian(?)

Comment: Yep. I translated it from Russian. So:
1. algorithmically finite (for groups) means that there is no algorithm for figuring infinite number of non-equal elements.
2. for algebras we consider this property as a algorithmically finite dimension.


Comment: it's obvious for finite groups and algebras (and any other structures), but the point is that they should be infinite 

Comment: @Ayrana Mongush: Please give the address of the Russian site.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl, thank you for editing tag fields.
@Boris Novikov, I can share the link of article about groups: http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what I could found is a talk of Bakhadyr Khoussainov

http://www.math.nsc.ru/conference/malmeet/11/plenary/2011MM_Khoussainov.ppt

in which he considered "algorithmically finite universal algebras". Maybe this will useful for you.